# Can't create an activity with an ActionBar

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-xml

I have just downloaded Eclipse and made an `ActionBarActivity` using the `android-support-v7-appcompat` and using sdk api 23. When I try to run the app I get this exception (Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) :

```
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270): Exception while inflating <vector>
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17<vector> tag requires viewportWidth > 0
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawableCompat.java:535)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.inflate(VectorDrawableCompat.java:472)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.createFromXmlInner(VectorDrawableCompat.java:436)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager$VdcInflateDelegate.createFromXmlInner(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:829)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:303)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:178)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:173)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:60)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:254)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:196)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:379)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:300)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:264)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at com.testing.name.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
02-27 00:42:13.266: E/VdcInflateDelegate(17270):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270): Process: com.testing.name, PID: 17270
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.testing.name/com.testing.name.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2328)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:379)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:300)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:264)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at com.testing.name.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    ... 11 more
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    ... 25 more
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020016
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3063)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1624)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.superGetDrawable(TintResources.java:48)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.onDrawableLoadedFromResources(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:374)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:44)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:323)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:180)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:173)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:60)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:254)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:196)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    ... 28 more
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:986)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:930)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3059)
02-27 00:42:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(17270):    ... 38 more
```

This is the application tag in the manifest which uses a style to the action bar:

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

and the style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="background">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTitleText</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarSubTitleText</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTitleText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/bluedark</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">28sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarSubTitleText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/bluedark</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">35sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

In the activity's graphical layout I don't even see the action bar.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a bug in the compatibility library. (Something to do with trying to inflate the compatability layout [abc_screen_toolbar.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/res/layout/abc_screen_toolbar.xml).)

There are a few ways to work around the issue when using the V7 library v23.2.0:

(in the order of easiest but poorest solution to the better but more involved alternatives at the end of the list)

- Revert to a version of the V7 library of v23.0.1 or earlier (instead of using 23.2.0)
- Use `compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.2.0'` *not* `compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.2.0@aar'` (note the absence of the `@aar` which is usually better but apparently not in this case)
- Switch to explicitly using the compatibility Toolbar widget in your layout instead of relying on the built-in, older `ActionBar` class. (See the Android Guide [Setting Up the App Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html) that uses `AppBarLayout` with a `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` and attached via a call to `setSupportActionBar()`.

Comment: I have indeed switched to the ToolBar